# Обводка у элементов JS скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Народ, всем привет. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Есть JS скрипт

```js
function init() {
    if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
          initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
          allowDrop: true,  // must be true to accept drops from the Palette
          "LinkDrawn": showLinkLabel,  // this DiagramEvent listener is defined below
          "LinkRelinked": showLinkLabel,
          "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
          "undoManager.isEnabled": true  // enable undo & redo
        });

    // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
    myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
      var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
      if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
      var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
      if (myDiagram.isModified) {
        if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
      } else {
        if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
        
      }
    });

    // helper definitions for node templates

    function nodeStyle() {
      return [
        // The Node.location comes from the "loc" property of the node data,
        // converted by the Point.parse static method.
        // If the Node.location is changed, it updates the "loc" property of the node data,
        // converting back using the Point.stringify static method.
        new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
        {
          // the Node.location is at the center of each node
          locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
          //isShadowed: true,
          //shadowColor: "#888",
          // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
          mouseEnter: function (e, obj) { showPorts(obj.part, true); },
          mouseLeave: function (e, obj) { showPorts(obj.part, false); }
        }
      ];
    }

    // Define a function for creating a "port" that is normally transparent.
    // The "name" is used as the GraphObject.portId, the "spot" is used to control how links connect
    // and where the port is positioned on the node, and the boolean "output" and "input" arguments
    // control whether the user can draw links from or to the port.
    function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
      // the port is basically just a small circle that has a white stroke when it is made visible
      return $(go.Shape, "Circle",
               {
                  fill: "transparent",
                  stroke: null,  // this is changed to "white" in the showPorts function
                  desiredSize: new go.Size(8, 8),
                  alignment: spot, alignmentFocus: spot,  // align the port on the main Shape
                  portId: name,  // declare this object to be a "port"
                  fromSpot: spot, toSpot: spot,  // declare where links may connect at this port
                  fromLinkable: output, toLinkable: input,  // declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
                  cursor: "pointer"  // show a different cursor to indicate potential link point
               });
    }

    // define the Node templates for regular nodes

    var lightText = 'whitesmoke';

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("",  // the default category
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a rectangular Shape
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
            { fill: "#444444", stroke: null },
            new go.Binding("figure", "figure")),
          $(go.TextBlock,
            {
              font: "500 14px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
              stroke: lightText,
              margin: 13,
              maxSize: new go.Size(300, NaN),
              wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
              editable: true
            },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        ),
        // four named ports, one on each side:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Start",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Circle",
            { minSize: new go.Size(70, 70), fill: "#444", stroke: null }),
          $(go.TextBlock, "Start",
            { font: "500 16px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome", stroke: lightText },
            new go.Binding("text"))
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));
  
    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Yellowish",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", { width: "50", height: "5", margin: 5, fill: null }),
          $(go.TextBlock, "Start",
            { font: "500 14px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome", stroke: "black" },
            new go.Binding("text"))
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("End",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "Circle",
            { minSize: new go.Size(70, 70), fill: "#000000", stroke: null }),
          $(go.TextBlock, "End",
            { font: "500 15px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome", stroke: lightText },
            new go.Binding("text"))
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the bottom, all input only:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, false, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, false, true)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Comment",
      $(go.Node, "Auto", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, "Circle",
          { minSize: new go.Size(70, 70), fill: "#f0f0f0", stroke: null }),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          {
            margin: 5,
            maxSize: new go.Size(100, NaN),
            wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
            textAlign: "center",
            editable: true,
            font: "500 13px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: '#454545'
          },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        // no ports, because no links are allowed to connect with a comment
      ));


    // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
          routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
          curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
          corner: 5, toShortLength: 4,
          relinkableFrom: true,
          relinkableTo: true,
          reshapable: true,
          resegmentable: true,
          // mouse-overs subtly highlight links:
          mouseEnter: function(e, link) { link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = ""; },
          mouseLeave: function(e, link) { link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "transparent"; }
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        $(go.Shape,  // the highlight shape, normally transparent
          { isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 1, stroke: "transparent", name: "HIGHLIGHT" }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link path shape
          { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "#AAAAAA", strokeWidth: 1 }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
          { toArrow: "standard", stroke: null, fill: "#AAAAAA"}),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",  // the link label, normally not visible
          { visible: false, name: "LABEL", segmentIndex: 2, segmentFraction: 0.9},
          new go.Binding("visible", "visible").makeTwoWay(),
          $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",  // the label shape
            { fill: "#fff", stroke: null }),
          $(go.TextBlock, "Yes",  // the label
            {
              textAlign: "center",
              font: "10pt Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
              stroke: "#333333",
              editable: true
            },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        )
      );

    // Make link labels visible if coming out of a "conditional" node.
    // This listener is called by the "LinkDrawn" and "LinkRelinked" DiagramEvents.
    function showLinkLabel(e) {
      var label = e.subject.findObject("LABEL");
      if (label !== null) label.visible = (e.subject.fromNode.data.figure === "Circle2");
      
    }

    // temporary links used by LinkingTool and RelinkingTool are also orthogonal:
    myDiagram.toolManager.linkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
    myDiagram.toolManager.relinkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;

    load();  // load an initial diagram from some JSON text

    // initialize the Palette that is on the left side of the page
    myPalette =
      $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
          "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
          nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,  // share the templates used by myDiagram
          model: new go.GraphLinksModel([  // specify the contents of the Palette
            { category: "Start", text: "33" },
            { text: "11" },
            { text: "222", figure: "Circle2" },
            { category: "End", text: "33" },
            { category: "Comment", text: "33" }
          ])
        });

    // The following code overrides GoJS focus to stop the browser from scrolling
    // the page when either the Diagram or Palette are clicked or dragged onto.

    function customFocus() {
      var x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
      var y = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
      go.Diagram.prototype.doFocus.call(this);
      window.scrollTo(x, y);
    }

    myDiagram.doFocus = customFocus;
    myPalette.doFocus = customFocus;


  } // end init

  // Make all ports on a node visible when the mouse is over the node
  function showPorts(node, show) {
    var diagram = node.diagram;
    if (!diagram || diagram.isReadOnly || !diagram.allowLink) return;
    node.ports.each(function(port) {
        port.stroke = (show ? "white" : null);
      });
  }


  // Show the diagram's model in JSON format that the user may edit
  function save() {
    document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
    myDiagram.isModified = false;
  }
  function load() {
    myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
  }

  // add an SVG rendering of the diagram at the end of this page
  function makeSVG() {
    var svg = myDiagram.makeSvg({
        scale: 0.5
      });
    svg.style.border = "1px solid #f0f0f0";
    obj = document.getElementById("SVGArea");
    obj.appendChild(svg);
    if (obj.children.length > 0) {
      obj.replaceChild(svg, obj.children[0]);
    }
  }

init();
```

```html
<div id="sample">
  <div style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:100px">
      <div id="myPaletteDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
    </span>

    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:80%">
      <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>
  The FlowChart sample demonstrates several key features of GoJS,
  namely <a href="../intro/palette.html">Palette</a>s,
  <a href="../intro/links.html">Linkable nodes</a>, Drag/Drop behavior,
  <a href="../intro/textBlocks.html">Text Editing</a>, and the use of
  <a href="../intro/templateMaps.html">Node Template Maps</a> in Diagrams.
  </p>
  <p>
  Mouse-over a Node to view its ports.
  Drag from these ports to create new Links.
  Selecting Links allows you to re-shape and re-link them.
  Selecting a Node and then clicking its TextBlock will allow
  you to edit text (except on the Start and End Nodes).
  </p>
  <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
  <button onclick="load()">Load</button>
  Diagram Model saved in JSON format:
  <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:300px">{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "linkFromPortIdProperty": "fromPort",
  "linkToPortIdProperty": "toPort",
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"key":-1, "loc":"175 0","category":"Yellowish", "text":"Plan Execution"},
{"key":0, "loc":"-8.000000000000014 80", "text":"Manual Execution"},
{"key":1, "loc":"175 121.99999999999993", "text":"Presighting"},
{"key":5, "loc":"365.00000000000006 81.00000000000006", "text":"Automation"},
{"text":"Sighting", "key":-2, "loc":"175 188"},
{"text":"Class TP Escape", "key":-7, "loc":"-106 254"},
{"text":"Silicone / Circuit / Spec Bug", "key":-8, "loc":"63 262"},
{"text":"SW / FW Bug", "key":-9, "loc":"226 256"},
{"text":"Periphery Bug", "key":-10, "loc":"386 256"},
{"text":"Test Content\nBug", "key":-11, "loc":"537 264"},
{"key":-12, "loc":"183 368", "text":"Stabilize"}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": [ 
{"from":5, "to":1, "fromPort":"A", "toPort":"T", "points":[315.50000000000006,81.00000000000006,305.50000000000006,81.00000000000006,175,81.00000000000006,175,88.35,175,95.69999999999993,175,105.69999999999993]},
{"from":0, "to":1, "fromPort":"A", "toPort":"T", "points":[62.499999999999986,80,72.49999999999999,80,175,80,175,87.84999999999997,175,95.69999999999993,175,105.69999999999993]},
{"from":-1, "to":0, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,16.3,175,26.3,175,40,-8.000000000000014,40,-8.000000000000014,53.7,-8.000000000000014,63.7]},
{"from":-1, "to":5, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,16.3,175,26.3,175,40.50000000000003,365.00000000000006,40.50000000000003,365.00000000000006,54.70000000000006,365.00000000000006,64.70000000000006]},
{"from":1, "to":-2, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,138.29999999999993,175,148.29999999999993,175,154.99999999999994,175,154.99999999999994,175,161.7,175,171.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-7, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,221,-106,221,-106,227.7,-106,237.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-8, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,221.1,63,221.1,63,227.9,63,237.9]},
{"from":-2, "to":-9, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222,226,222,226,229.7,226,239.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-10, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222,386,222,386,229.7,386,239.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-11, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222.1,537,222.1,537,229.9,537,239.9]},
{"from":-9, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[226,272.3,226,282.3,226,312,183,312,183,341.7,183,351.7]},
{"from":-8, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"L", "points":[63,286.1,63,296.1,63,368,99,368,135,368,145,368]},
{"from":-7, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"L", "points":[-106,270.3,-106,280.3,-106,368,14.5,368,135,368,145,368]},
{"from":-10, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"R", "points":[386,272.3,386,282.3,386,368,308.5,368,231,368,221,368]},
{"from":-11, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"R", "points":[537,288.1,537,298.1,537,368,384,368,231,368,221,368]},
{"from":-12, "to":-1, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[183,384.30000000000007,183,394.30000000000007,183,396,132,396,132,340,140,340,140,228,108,228,108,-28,175,-28,175,-26.3,175,-16.3]}
 ]}
  </textarea>
  <p>Click the button below to render the current GoJS Diagram into SVG at one-half scale.
     The SVG is not interactive like the GoJS diagram, but can be used for printing or display.
     For more information, see the page on <a href="../intro/makingSVG.html">making SVG</a>.</p>
  <button onclick="makeSVG()">Render as SVG</button>
  <div id="SVGArea"></div>
</div><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.6.23/go.js'></script>
```

при клике на элемент он выдает синюю обводку от которой хотелось бы избавится. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает как это сделать. Гугл помог частично - (http://code.mu/ru/javascript/manual/canvas/strokeStyle/), но после внедрения данного куска в код - скрипт перестает работать.

Comment: так как ты используешь конкретную библиотеку, стоит смотреть справку именно по ней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За показ данной рамки отвечает свойство [`selectionAdorned`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html#selectionAdorned). Чтобы убрать ее, достаточно указать этому свойству значение `false`.

Подробнее про выделение можно посмотреть [в справке](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/selection.html#SelectionAdornments)

```js
function init() {
  if (window.goSamples) goSamples(); // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make; // for conciseness in defining templates

  myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
      {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        allowDrop: true, // must be true to accept drops from the Palette
        "LinkDrawn": showLinkLabel, // this DiagramEvent listener is defined below
        "LinkRelinked": showLinkLabel,
        "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true // enable undo & redo
      });

  // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
    var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
    if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
    var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
    if (myDiagram.isModified) {
      if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
    } else {
      if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);

    }
  });

  // helper definitions for node templates

  function nodeStyle() {
    return [
      // The Node.location comes from the "loc" property of the node data,
      // converted by the Point.parse static method.
      // If the Node.location is changed, it updates the "loc" property of the node data,
      // converting back using the Point.stringify static method.
      new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
      {
        // the Node.location is at the center of each node
        locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
        //isShadowed: true,
        //shadowColor: "#888",
        // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
        mouseEnter: function(e, obj) {
          showPorts(obj.part, true);
        },
        mouseLeave: function(e, obj) {
          showPorts(obj.part, false);
        },
        // отключаем выделение////////////
        selectionAdorned: false    ///////
        //////////////////////////////////
      }
    ];
  }

  // Define a function for creating a "port" that is normally transparent.
  // The "name" is used as the GraphObject.portId, the "spot" is used to control how links connect
  // and where the port is positioned on the node, and the boolean "output" and "input" arguments
  // control whether the user can draw links from or to the port.
  function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
    // the port is basically just a small circle that has a white stroke when it is made visible
    return $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
      fill: "transparent",
      stroke: null, // this is changed to "white" in the showPorts function
      desiredSize: new go.Size(8, 8),
      alignment: spot,
      alignmentFocus: spot, // align the port on the main Shape
      portId: name, // declare this object to be a "port"
      fromSpot: spot,
      toSpot: spot, // declare where links may connect at this port
      fromLinkable: output,
      toLinkable: input, // declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
      cursor: "pointer" // show a different cursor to indicate potential link point
    });
  }

  // define the Node templates for regular nodes

  var lightText = 'whitesmoke';

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("", // the default category
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a rectangular Shape
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
            fill: "#444444",
            stroke: null
          },
          new go.Binding("figure", "figure")),
        $(go.TextBlock, {
            font: "500 14px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: lightText,
            margin: 13,
            maxSize: new go.Size(300, NaN),
            wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
            editable: true
          },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      ),
      // four named ports, one on each side:
      makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
      makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Start",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
          minSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
          fill: "#444",
          stroke: null
        }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "Start", {
            font: "500 16px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: lightText
          },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
      makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Yellowish",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
          width: "50",
          height: "5",
          margin: 5,
          fill: null
        }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "Start", {
            font: "500 14px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: "black"
          },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
      makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("End",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
          minSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
          fill: "#000000",
          stroke: null
        }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "End", {
            font: "500 15px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: lightText
          },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      // three named ports, one on each side except the bottom, all input only:
      makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, false, true),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, false, true)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Comment",
    $(go.Node, "Auto", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
        minSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
        fill: "#f0f0f0",
        stroke: null
      }),
      $(go.TextBlock, {
          margin: 5,
          maxSize: new go.Size(100, NaN),
          wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
          textAlign: "center",
          editable: true,
          font: "500 13px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
          stroke: '#454545'
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      // no ports, because no links are allowed to connect with a comment
    ));


  // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link, // the whole link panel
      {
        routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
        curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
        corner: 5,
        toShortLength: 4,
        relinkableFrom: true,
        relinkableTo: true,
        reshapable: true,
        resegmentable: true,
        // mouse-overs subtly highlight links:
        mouseEnter: function(e, link) {
          link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "";
        },
        mouseLeave: function(e, link) {
          link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "transparent";
        }
      },
      new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
      $(go.Shape, // the highlight shape, normally transparent
        {
          isPanelMain: true,
          strokeWidth: 1,
          stroke: "transparent",
          name: "HIGHLIGHT"
        }),
      $(go.Shape, // the link path shape
        {
          isPanelMain: true,
          stroke: "#AAAAAA",
          strokeWidth: 1
        }),
      $(go.Shape, // the arrowhead
        {
          toArrow: "standard",
          stroke: null,
          fill: "#AAAAAA"
        }),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto", // the link label, normally not visible
        {
          visible: false,
          name: "LABEL",
          segmentIndex: 2,
          segmentFraction: 0.9
        },
        new go.Binding("visible", "visible").makeTwoWay(),
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", // the label shape
          {
            fill: "#fff",
            stroke: null
          }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "Yes", // the label
          {
            textAlign: "center",
            font: "10pt Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: "#333333",
            editable: true
          },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      )
    );

  // Make link labels visible if coming out of a "conditional" node.
  // This listener is called by the "LinkDrawn" and "LinkRelinked" DiagramEvents.
  function showLinkLabel(e) {
    var label = e.subject.findObject("LABEL");
    if (label !== null) label.visible = (e.subject.fromNode.data.figure === "Circle2");

  }

  // temporary links used by LinkingTool and RelinkingTool are also orthogonal:
  myDiagram.toolManager.linkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
  myDiagram.toolManager.relinkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;

  load(); // load an initial diagram from some JSON text

  // initialize the Palette that is on the left side of the page
  myPalette =
    $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv", // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
      {
        "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
        nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap, // share the templates used by myDiagram
        model: new go.GraphLinksModel([ // specify the contents of the Palette
          {
            category: "Start",
            text: "33"
          },
          {
            text: "11"
          },
          {
            text: "222",
            figure: "Circle2"
          },
          {
            category: "End",
            text: "33"
          },
          {
            category: "Comment",
            text: "33"
          }
        ])
      });

  // The following code overrides GoJS focus to stop the browser from scrolling
  // the page when either the Diagram or Palette are clicked or dragged onto.

  function customFocus() {
    var x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
    var y = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    go.Diagram.prototype.doFocus.call(this);
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
  }

  myDiagram.doFocus = customFocus;
  myPalette.doFocus = customFocus;


} // end init

// Make all ports on a node visible when the mouse is over the node
function showPorts(node, show) {
  var diagram = node.diagram;
  if (!diagram || diagram.isReadOnly || !diagram.allowLink) return;
  node.ports.each(function(port) {
    port.stroke = (show ? "white" : null);
  });
}


// Show the diagram's model in JSON format that the user may edit
function save() {
  document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
  myDiagram.isModified = false;
}

function load() {
  myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
}

// add an SVG rendering of the diagram at the end of this page
function makeSVG() {
  var svg = myDiagram.makeSvg({
    scale: 0.5
  });
  svg.style.border = "1px solid #f0f0f0";
  obj = document.getElementById("SVGArea");
  obj.appendChild(svg);
  if (obj.children.length > 0) {
    obj.replaceChild(svg, obj.children[0]);
  }
}

init();
```

```html
<div id="sample">
  <div style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:100px">
      <div id="myPaletteDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
    </span>

    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:80%">
      <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>
    The FlowChart sample demonstrates several key features of GoJS, namely <a href="../intro/palette.html">Palette</a>s,
    <a href="../intro/links.html">Linkable nodes</a>, Drag/Drop behavior,
    <a href="../intro/textBlocks.html">Text Editing</a>, and the use of
    <a href="../intro/templateMaps.html">Node Template Maps</a> in Diagrams.
  </p>
  <p>
    Mouse-over a Node to view its ports. Drag from these ports to create new Links. Selecting Links allows you to re-shape and re-link them. Selecting a Node and then clicking its TextBlock will allow you to edit text (except on the Start and End Nodes).
  </p>
  <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
  <button onclick="load()">Load</button> Diagram Model saved in JSON format:
  <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:300px">{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "linkFromPortIdProperty": "fromPort",
  "linkToPortIdProperty": "toPort",
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"key":-1, "loc":"175 0","category":"Yellowish", "text":"Plan Execution"},
{"key":0, "loc":"-8.000000000000014 80", "text":"Manual Execution"},
{"key":1, "loc":"175 121.99999999999993", "text":"Presighting"},
{"key":5, "loc":"365.00000000000006 81.00000000000006", "text":"Automation"},
{"text":"Sighting", "key":-2, "loc":"175 188"},
{"text":"Class TP Escape", "key":-7, "loc":"-106 254"},
{"text":"Silicone / Circuit / Spec Bug", "key":-8, "loc":"63 262"},
{"text":"SW / FW Bug", "key":-9, "loc":"226 256"},
{"text":"Periphery Bug", "key":-10, "loc":"386 256"},
{"text":"Test Content\nBug", "key":-11, "loc":"537 264"},
{"key":-12, "loc":"183 368", "text":"Stabilize"}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": [ 
{"from":5, "to":1, "fromPort":"A", "toPort":"T", "points":[315.50000000000006,81.00000000000006,305.50000000000006,81.00000000000006,175,81.00000000000006,175,88.35,175,95.69999999999993,175,105.69999999999993]},
{"from":0, "to":1, "fromPort":"A", "toPort":"T", "points":[62.499999999999986,80,72.49999999999999,80,175,80,175,87.84999999999997,175,95.69999999999993,175,105.69999999999993]},
{"from":-1, "to":0, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,16.3,175,26.3,175,40,-8.000000000000014,40,-8.000000000000014,53.7,-8.000000000000014,63.7]},
{"from":-1, "to":5, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,16.3,175,26.3,175,40.50000000000003,365.00000000000006,40.50000000000003,365.00000000000006,54.70000000000006,365.00000000000006,64.70000000000006]},
{"from":1, "to":-2, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,138.29999999999993,175,148.29999999999993,175,154.99999999999994,175,154.99999999999994,175,161.7,175,171.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-7, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,221,-106,221,-106,227.7,-106,237.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-8, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,221.1,63,221.1,63,227.9,63,237.9]},
{"from":-2, "to":-9, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222,226,222,226,229.7,226,239.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-10, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222,386,222,386,229.7,386,239.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-11, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222.1,537,222.1,537,229.9,537,239.9]},
{"from":-9, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[226,272.3,226,282.3,226,312,183,312,183,341.7,183,351.7]},
{"from":-8, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"L", "points":[63,286.1,63,296.1,63,368,99,368,135,368,145,368]},
{"from":-7, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"L", "points":[-106,270.3,-106,280.3,-106,368,14.5,368,135,368,145,368]},
{"from":-10, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"R", "points":[386,272.3,386,282.3,386,368,308.5,368,231,368,221,368]},
{"from":-11, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"R", "points":[537,288.1,537,298.1,537,368,384,368,231,368,221,368]},
{"from":-12, "to":-1, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[183,384.30000000000007,183,394.30000000000007,183,396,132,396,132,340,140,340,140,228,108,228,108,-28,175,-28,175,-26.3,175,-16.3]}
 ]}
  </textarea>
  <p>Click the button below to render the current GoJS Diagram into SVG at one-half scale. The SVG is not interactive like the GoJS diagram, but can be used for printing or display. For more information, see the page on <a href="../intro/makingSVG.html">making SVG</a>.</p>
  <button onclick="makeSVG()">Render as SVG</button>
  <div id="SVGArea"></div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.6.23/go.js'></script>
```

Comment: Огроменное спасибо! Нереальная помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Я прописал вам следующий стиль

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}
```

```js
function init() {
  if (window.goSamples) goSamples(); // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make; // for conciseness in defining templates

  myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
      {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        allowDrop: true, // must be true to accept drops from the Palette
        "LinkDrawn": showLinkLabel, // this DiagramEvent listener is defined below
        "LinkRelinked": showLinkLabel,
        "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true // enable undo & redo
      });

  // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
    var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
    if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
    var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
    if (myDiagram.isModified) {
      if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
    } else {
      if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);

    }
  });

  // helper definitions for node templates

  function nodeStyle() {
    return [
      // The Node.location comes from the "loc" property of the node data,
      // converted by the Point.parse static method.
      // If the Node.location is changed, it updates the "loc" property of the node data,
      // converting back using the Point.stringify static method.
      new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
      {
        // the Node.location is at the center of each node
        locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
        //isShadowed: true,
        //shadowColor: "#888",
        // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
        mouseEnter: function(e, obj) {
          showPorts(obj.part, true);
        },
        mouseLeave: function(e, obj) {
          showPorts(obj.part, false);
        }
      }
    ];
  }

  // Define a function for creating a "port" that is normally transparent.
  // The "name" is used as the GraphObject.portId, the "spot" is used to control how links connect
  // and where the port is positioned on the node, and the boolean "output" and "input" arguments
  // control whether the user can draw links from or to the port.
  function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
    // the port is basically just a small circle that has a white stroke when it is made visible
    return $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
      fill: "transparent",
      stroke: null, // this is changed to "white" in the showPorts function
      desiredSize: new go.Size(8, 8),
      alignment: spot,
      alignmentFocus: spot, // align the port on the main Shape
      portId: name, // declare this object to be a "port"
      fromSpot: spot,
      toSpot: spot, // declare where links may connect at this port
      fromLinkable: output,
      toLinkable: input, // declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
      cursor: "pointer" // show a different cursor to indicate potential link point
    });
  }

  // define the Node templates for regular nodes

  var lightText = 'whitesmoke';

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("", // the default category
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a rectangular Shape
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
            fill: "#444444",
            stroke: null
          },
          new go.Binding("figure", "figure")),
        $(go.TextBlock, {
            font: "500 14px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: lightText,
            margin: 13,
            maxSize: new go.Size(300, NaN),
            wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
            editable: true
          },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      ),
      // four named ports, one on each side:
      makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
      makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Start",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
          minSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
          fill: "#444",
          stroke: null
        }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "Start", {
            font: "500 16px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: lightText
          },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
      makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Yellowish",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
          width: "50",
          height: "5",
          margin: 5,
          fill: null
        }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "Start", {
            font: "500 14px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: "black"
          },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
      makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("End",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
          minSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
          fill: "#000000",
          stroke: null
        }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "End", {
            font: "500 15px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: lightText
          },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      // three named ports, one on each side except the bottom, all input only:
      makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
      makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, false, true),
      makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, false, true)
    ));

  myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Comment",
    $(go.Node, "Auto", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
        minSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
        fill: "#f0f0f0",
        stroke: null
      }),
      $(go.TextBlock, {
          margin: 5,
          maxSize: new go.Size(100, NaN),
          wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
          textAlign: "center",
          editable: true,
          font: "500 13px Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
          stroke: '#454545'
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      // no ports, because no links are allowed to connect with a comment
    ));


  // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link, // the whole link panel
      {
        routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
        curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
        corner: 5,
        toShortLength: 4,
        relinkableFrom: true,
        relinkableTo: true,
        reshapable: true,
        resegmentable: true,
        // mouse-overs subtly highlight links:
        mouseEnter: function(e, link) {
          link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "";
        },
        mouseLeave: function(e, link) {
          link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "transparent";
        }
      },
      new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
      $(go.Shape, // the highlight shape, normally transparent
        {
          isPanelMain: true,
          strokeWidth: 1,
          stroke: "transparent",
          name: "HIGHLIGHT"
        }),
      $(go.Shape, // the link path shape
        {
          isPanelMain: true,
          stroke: "#AAAAAA",
          strokeWidth: 1
        }),
      $(go.Shape, // the arrowhead
        {
          toArrow: "standard",
          stroke: null,
          fill: "#AAAAAA"
        }),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto", // the link label, normally not visible
        {
          visible: false,
          name: "LABEL",
          segmentIndex: 2,
          segmentFraction: 0.9
        },
        new go.Binding("visible", "visible").makeTwoWay(),
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", // the label shape
          {
            fill: "#fff",
            stroke: null
          }),
        $(go.TextBlock, "Yes", // the label
          {
            textAlign: "center",
            font: "10pt Montserrat Alternates, FontAwesome",
            stroke: "#333333",
            editable: true
          },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      )
    );

  // Make link labels visible if coming out of a "conditional" node.
  // This listener is called by the "LinkDrawn" and "LinkRelinked" DiagramEvents.
  function showLinkLabel(e) {
    var label = e.subject.findObject("LABEL");
    if (label !== null) label.visible = (e.subject.fromNode.data.figure === "Circle2");

  }

  // temporary links used by LinkingTool and RelinkingTool are also orthogonal:
  myDiagram.toolManager.linkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
  myDiagram.toolManager.relinkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;

  load(); // load an initial diagram from some JSON text

  // initialize the Palette that is on the left side of the page
  myPalette =
    $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv", // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
      {
        "animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
        nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap, // share the templates used by myDiagram
        model: new go.GraphLinksModel([ // specify the contents of the Palette
          {
            category: "Start",
            text: "33"
          },
          {
            text: "11"
          },
          {
            text: "222",
            figure: "Circle2"
          },
          {
            category: "End",
            text: "33"
          },
          {
            category: "Comment",
            text: "33"
          }
        ])
      });

  // The following code overrides GoJS focus to stop the browser from scrolling
  // the page when either the Diagram or Palette are clicked or dragged onto.

  function customFocus() {
    var x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
    var y = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    go.Diagram.prototype.doFocus.call(this);
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
  }

  myDiagram.doFocus = customFocus;
  myPalette.doFocus = customFocus;


} // end init

// Make all ports on a node visible when the mouse is over the node
function showPorts(node, show) {
  var diagram = node.diagram;
  if (!diagram || diagram.isReadOnly || !diagram.allowLink) return;
  node.ports.each(function(port) {
    port.stroke = (show ? "white" : null);
  });
}


// Show the diagram's model in JSON format that the user may edit
function save() {
  document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
  myDiagram.isModified = false;
}

function load() {
  myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
}

// add an SVG rendering of the diagram at the end of this page
function makeSVG() {
  var svg = myDiagram.makeSvg({
    scale: 0.5
  });
  svg.style.border = "1px solid #f0f0f0";
  obj = document.getElementById("SVGArea");
  obj.appendChild(svg);
  if (obj.children.length > 0) {
    obj.replaceChild(svg, obj.children[0]);
  }
}

init();
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">
  <div style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:100px">
      <div id="myPaletteDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
    </span>

    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:80%">
      <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 720px"></div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>
    The FlowChart sample demonstrates several key features of GoJS, namely <a href="../intro/palette.html">Palette</a>s,
    <a href="../intro/links.html">Linkable nodes</a>, Drag/Drop behavior,
    <a href="../intro/textBlocks.html">Text Editing</a>, and the use of
    <a href="../intro/templateMaps.html">Node Template Maps</a> in Diagrams.
  </p>
  <p>
    Mouse-over a Node to view its ports. Drag from these ports to create new Links. Selecting Links allows you to re-shape and re-link them. Selecting a Node and then clicking its TextBlock will allow you to edit text (except on the Start and End Nodes).
  </p>
  <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
  <button onclick="load()">Load</button> Diagram Model saved in JSON format:
  <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:300px">{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "linkFromPortIdProperty": "fromPort",
  "linkToPortIdProperty": "toPort",
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"key":-1, "loc":"175 0","category":"Yellowish", "text":"Plan Execution"},
{"key":0, "loc":"-8.000000000000014 80", "text":"Manual Execution"},
{"key":1, "loc":"175 121.99999999999993", "text":"Presighting"},
{"key":5, "loc":"365.00000000000006 81.00000000000006", "text":"Automation"},
{"text":"Sighting", "key":-2, "loc":"175 188"},
{"text":"Class TP Escape", "key":-7, "loc":"-106 254"},
{"text":"Silicone / Circuit / Spec Bug", "key":-8, "loc":"63 262"},
{"text":"SW / FW Bug", "key":-9, "loc":"226 256"},
{"text":"Periphery Bug", "key":-10, "loc":"386 256"},
{"text":"Test Content\nBug", "key":-11, "loc":"537 264"},
{"key":-12, "loc":"183 368", "text":"Stabilize"}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": [ 
{"from":5, "to":1, "fromPort":"A", "toPort":"T", "points":[315.50000000000006,81.00000000000006,305.50000000000006,81.00000000000006,175,81.00000000000006,175,88.35,175,95.69999999999993,175,105.69999999999993]},
{"from":0, "to":1, "fromPort":"A", "toPort":"T", "points":[62.499999999999986,80,72.49999999999999,80,175,80,175,87.84999999999997,175,95.69999999999993,175,105.69999999999993]},
{"from":-1, "to":0, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,16.3,175,26.3,175,40,-8.000000000000014,40,-8.000000000000014,53.7,-8.000000000000014,63.7]},
{"from":-1, "to":5, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,16.3,175,26.3,175,40.50000000000003,365.00000000000006,40.50000000000003,365.00000000000006,54.70000000000006,365.00000000000006,64.70000000000006]},
{"from":1, "to":-2, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,138.29999999999993,175,148.29999999999993,175,154.99999999999994,175,154.99999999999994,175,161.7,175,171.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-7, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,221,-106,221,-106,227.7,-106,237.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-8, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,221.1,63,221.1,63,227.9,63,237.9]},
{"from":-2, "to":-9, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222,226,222,226,229.7,226,239.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-10, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222,386,222,386,229.7,386,239.7]},
{"from":-2, "to":-11, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[175,204.29999999999998,175,214.29999999999998,175,222.1,537,222.1,537,229.9,537,239.9]},
{"from":-9, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[226,272.3,226,282.3,226,312,183,312,183,341.7,183,351.7]},
{"from":-8, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"L", "points":[63,286.1,63,296.1,63,368,99,368,135,368,145,368]},
{"from":-7, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"L", "points":[-106,270.3,-106,280.3,-106,368,14.5,368,135,368,145,368]},
{"from":-10, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"R", "points":[386,272.3,386,282.3,386,368,308.5,368,231,368,221,368]},
{"from":-11, "to":-12, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"R", "points":[537,288.1,537,298.1,537,368,384,368,231,368,221,368]},
{"from":-12, "to":-1, "fromPort":"B", "toPort":"T", "points":[183,384.30000000000007,183,394.30000000000007,183,396,132,396,132,340,140,340,140,228,108,228,108,-28,175,-28,175,-26.3,175,-16.3]}
 ]}
  </textarea>
  <p>Click the button below to render the current GoJS Diagram into SVG at one-half scale. The SVG is not interactive like the GoJS diagram, but can be used for printing or display. For more information, see the page on <a href="../intro/makingSVG.html">making SVG</a>.</p>
  <button onclick="makeSVG()">Render as SVG</button>
  <div id="SVGArea"></div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.6.23/go.js'></script>
```

Comment: К сожалению это не работает. a:active, a:focus { outline: none !important; }

input, textarea {outline:none !important;}
input:active, textarea:active {outline:none !important;}
:focus {outline:none !important;}
textarea {resize:none !important;}
textarea {resize:vertical !important;}
textarea {resize:horizontal !important;} Я прописал все эти стили и они не работают.

Comment: @Nihroms выше запустите код, вы разве видите синюю обводку?

Comment: @Daart, кликни на элемент диаграммы и обводка появится